# Как ввести в вектор неизвестной длины последовательность целых чисел построчно из файла?

Tags: c++

Например
123 11 1 -1\n
1\n
1 2 3\n
1 вектор (123,11,1,-1)
2 вектор (1)
3 вектор (1,2,3)

Comment: vector<vector<int>>, map<int, vector<int>> и т.д

Comment: В заголовке сказано "вектор", а в тексте упоминается набор векторов. Так что же именно вам нужно? Несколько отдельных векторов? Массив (вектор) векторов?

Comment: а почему бы не использовать xml или json для того, чтобы записать корректно, в человекочитаемом виде, подобные данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала определим структуру данных, которая содержится в файле. Я не знаю в чем сакральный смысл этих чисел, поэтому моя структура будет называтся просто `Line`. У вас имя должно быть более осмысленное.

```
class Line{
    std::vector<int> _data;
public:
    const std::vector<int>& data() const
    {
        return _data;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Line &line);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Line &line);
};
```

У этой структуры есть операторы чтения и записи. `operator>>` читает одну строку из потока ввода, и вычитывает из нее инты:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Line &line)
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(is, str);
    std::istringstream ss{str};
    line._data.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>{ss}, {});

    return is;
}
```

`operator<<` просто выводит свое содержимое в поток через пробел:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Line &line)
{
    std::copy(line._data.begin(), line._data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{os, " "});

    return os;
}
```

---

Теперь, после того как мы открыли файл:

```
std::ifstream data{"data.txt"};
```

для того чтобы прочитать все его содержимое, нам понадобится всего одна строчка кода:

```
std::vector<Line> lines(std::istream_iterator<Line>{data}, {});
```

[Код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c231536ccbaddac7)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, череж `stringstream`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream f("data");
    string s;
    vector<vector<int>> v;

    while (getline(f, s)) {
        istringstream ss(s);
        vector<int> vv;
        int n;

        while (ss >> n) vv.push_back(n);

        v.push_back(vv);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Vector " << i + 1 << ":";

        for (int j : v[i]) cout << " " << j;

        cout << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я бы еще добавил `std::move` в `v.push_back(vv);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, неплохой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно читать определенное количество строк, то я предложу вариант попроще(без дополнительных обьектов):

```
std::vector< std::vector<int>>
read_line(istream& file, const size_t row) {
    vector< vector<int> > vs(row);
    int n{};
    vector<int> v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; ++i) {  
        //читаем до конца строки с заполнением в вектор
        while (file.peek() != '\n' && file >> n) 
            v.push_back(n); 
        vs[i] = v;
        // опустошаем вектор для следующего цикла
        v.clear();
        // игнорирум символ '\n'
        file.ignore(); 
    }
    return vs;
}
```